# Angular 8 ng build --prod gives Error during template compile of 'Injectable'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I upgraded from angular 6 to 8 and updated all the libraries used in the project. Everything seems to be running fine but when I use ng build --prod, I get these errors

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Directive'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'NgModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'NgModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
Error during template compile of 'Injectable'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called.
```

I already searched for solutions and got things like changing absolute path to relative.
I did that still I get these issues

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "centilytics-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-angular": "^2.1.1",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.5.6",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.1.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "@sedeh/wizard-storage": "^1.2.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^21.0.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.0.1",
    "aws-mqtt": "^0.2.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.289.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-gauge": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.7.6",
    "ngx-summernote": "^0.6.5",
    "paho-mqtt": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "values.js": "^1.0.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.1",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding this to tsconfig.json worked for me

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "@angular/*": [ "node_modules/@angular/*"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a regression (a behavior that used to work and stopped working in a new release) open ticket for this issue. And under that issue there is the solution: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609#issuecomment-386876693

Comment: Solution provided is not working. It used to build fine on angular 6

Comment: Error messages are vague and dont specify where exactly is issue

Comment: It's fixed. There was issue with one of the library

Comment: @DhananjayKaushik not posible to share the source of the issue?